# How to start Virtual Box service on Linux

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, services

I performed a `dist-upgrade` and then and `autoclean` and `autoremove`. It disabled the Virtual Box service on Linux because the headers were out of date. The headers caught up, so I rebuilt the modules off the Guest Additions CD.

I'm trying to start the service again, but I can't seem to find the command. For example, I found [How to automatically start and shut down VirtualBox machines?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28611/56041), but it talks about using the Virtual Box manager and not Ubuntu's service control.

How do I start How to start Virtual Box service on Ubuntu Linux?

If needed, how do I reinstall the Virtual Box service on Ubuntu Linux?

Answer (score 3):

On my Deepin Linux (a variant of Ubuntu), I know two ways to start the Virtualbox services.

1. In the terminal type `service --status-all` -- It will list the services registered in system with the status mentioned in output. You can see VirtualBox related services with the name `vbox`*.
2. This step is now trivial. To start a service type `service service_name start` where service_name is the service name you saw in step 1. E.g.: If the service name is `vboxautostart-service` then type `service vboxautostart-service start`.

Or,

1. Go into `/etc/init.d`. Type `ls -l` to list files (services) and look for services with the name `vbox`*. Make sure that they are executable.
2. Executing them is similar to executing a binary. E.g.: To start `vboxdrv` service, the command would be `./vboxdrv start`.

In both the methods, you can choose not to issue `start` to see all parameters available for the service.